# xargs not working as expected

Tags: linux, mac

On Mac:

```
sudo powermetrics --samplers smc  | xargs
```

Never produces any output. Without xargs, it correctly writes my computer's power metrics.

```
   Machine model: ...
   SMC version: ...
   EFI version: ...
   OS version: ...
   Boot arguments: ...
   Boot time: ...
```

Why?

I actually wanted to do

```
sudo powermetrics --samplers smc | ts
```

and it produced the same empty result. Thought this is a simpler example.

Comment: It may help to also include what is `expected`

Comment: A non-zero-length output is expected.

Comment: Let's try it again. What do you expect to happen / to be output when you run the command `sudo powermetrics --samplers smc  | xargs`?

Comment: Something along the lines of `Machine model: ...
   SMC version: ...
   EFI version: ...
   OS version: ...
   Boot arguments: ...
   Boot time: ...` and then more output every minute or so.

Comment: @Ruby So is it that you want to be able to run the command `sudo powermetrics --samplers smc` every minute or so? It's not clear what your objective is in the original question. If you just want to run `sudo powermeterics --samplers smc` every minute or so and see a timestamp, you could just do `watch -n60 sudo powermetrics --samplers smc`. If that's not what you want, you need to explain more in your question.

Comment: I run the command once, but it runs indefinitely, periodically writing some output. I found the problem, it must have realized it's not writing to a terminal and is buffering. A strange decision. Any way to fool it into thinking it has a terminal?